# Importing Components with React/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx, react-tsx

I want to import Test component into Home but I keep getting the following error:

```
Module '"/.../src/components/Test"' has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { Test } from "/.../src/components/Test"' instead?
```

In the test component I keep getting the following error on exporting Test:

```
Type '({ name }: Props) => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<Props>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'
```

Test component

```
import React,{FC} from 'react';

interface Props {
  name: string;
}
export const Test:FC<Props> = ({ name }: Props) => {
  <div>{name}</div>
};
```

Home component

```
import React from 'react';
import Test from './Test'

export const Home = () => {
  <div><Test name="example" /></div>
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. The error has to do with how ES6 arrow functions (or ES Modules) work.

So allow me to explain: you're geting a TypeScript error because your `Test` component doesn't actually `return` the JSX you're creating.

```js
export const Test:FC<Props> = ({ name }: Props) => (
  <div>{name}</div>
);
```

If you were to replace the curly braces with parens, your code works fine.

Furthermore, named exports are not equal to `default` export. In your example, you're exporting `Test` via `export const Test` and not `default`.

As you have not exported a default, `import Test from './test.tsx'` won't work.

I suggest you [read up on ES Modules](https://codeburst.io/understanding-es6-modules-import-export-syntax-in-javascript-6c01f20cead3), and [ES6 arrow functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-arrow-functions/).

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes? It answers the question, and resources are provided.